# derivation template classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written a template BST class with the usual operations like this:

```
template <class Key,class T>
class BTree {
public:
   BTree():root(0){}//crea un albero vuoto
   BTree<Key,T>& treeInsert(const Key& k,const T& val);
   BTree<Key,T>& treeDelete(const Key& k);
   Node<Key,T>& treeSearch(const Key& k);
   Node<Key,T>& treeMinimum();
   void treeClear();
protected:
   BTree<Key,T>& transplant(Node<Key,T>& n1,Node<Key,T>& n2);
   Node<Key,T>* root;
};
```

I would like to implements a template red-black tree class that inherits from the bst class.
The red-black class should rewrite the insertion and deletion, but I read that methods of a template class can not be virtual, and so do not know how to do this.

Comment: Methods of a class template can be virtual, it's just method templates that can't.

Comment: Do let me just ask if inheritance is the correct relationship for what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: my treeInsert() and my treeDelete  are not method templates?

Comment: I thought about using the inheritance because a red black tree is a binary search tree

Comment: @AlfredoLiardo No, they are non-template methods of a class template. Something like `template <typename NewParam> void FunctionTemplateExample()` inside `BTree` would be a method template.

Comment: @AlfredoLiardo You might want to look at [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). That might be a better alternative here.

Comment: So  can I use virtual with treeInsert and treeDelete and then override in red-black class?

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try the advice you have given me and will let you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you actually can have `virtual` functions in a template class, and those can be overridden by deriving classes.

---

Though the better choice IMHO might be, to use a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (aka Static Polymorphism, Policy based design) for such case (as you're already handing on templates). It could look like this

```
template <class Key,class T,class Derived>
                        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class BTree {
public:
   BTree():root(0){}//crea un albero vuoto
   BTree<Key,T>& treeInsert(const Key& k,const T& val) {
       return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->doTreeInsert();
   }
   BTree<Key,T>& treeDelete(const Key& k) {
       return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->doTreeDelete();
   }
   Node<Key,T>& treeSearch(const Key& k);
   Node<Key,T>& treeMinimum();
   void treeClear();
protected:
   BTree<Key,T>& transplant(Node<Key,T>& n1,Node<Key,T>& n2);
   Node<Key,T>* root;
};
```

Derived classes must implement `doTreeInsert()` and `doTreeDelete()` functions accordingly, to let this code compile:

```
template <class Key,class T>
class RedBlackTree 
: public BTree<Key,T,RedBlackTree> {
public:
   BTree<Key,T>& doTreeInsert(const Key& k,const T& val) {
       // Implement the RB specifics for insert here
       return *this;
   }
   BTree<Key,T>& doTreeDelete(const Key& k) {
       // Implement the RB specifics for delete here
       return *this;
   }
};
```

Comment: If I wanted use the simple treeInsert on a BTree ,How can I do?

Comment: @AlfredoLiardo You can still provide a _simple insert_ implementation `doTreeInsert()` in the template base class.