# Mismatched type error between `BaseChild<BaseParent>*` and `DerivedChild<DerivedParent>*`

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, forward-declaration, rvalue

I'm having trouble coming up with a good name for this question, and I apologize for that.  If after reading you have a better name, please let me know.  Anyways, I have some code similar to the following:

```
// BaseFamily.h
template<typename T>
class BaseChild {
  T parent;
}

class BaseParent {
  virtual BaseChild<BaseParent>* createChild() = 0;
}
```

.

```
// DerivedFamily.h
class DerivedParent;
class DerivedChild: public BaseChild<DerivedParent> {}

class DerivedParent
  : public BaseParent
{
  BaseChild<BaseParent>* createChild() override {
    return new DerivedChild();  
    // error: Cannot initialize return object of type 'BaseChild<BaseParent> *' with an rvalue of type 'DerivedChild *'
  }
}
```

Above is two sets of parent<->child circular references.  Further, the latter set inherits from the formers parent and child.  One of the things inherited is a function for creating a child which is overridden to return a DerivedChild instead of the BaseChild.

This seems like it should be at least close to working as a pointer to BaseChild should be able to handle pointing to DerivedChild, but these appear to not be interchangable with any syntax I know of.

To put it in a question: **How can I make a function of return type `BaseChild<BaseParent>*` that will allow `DerivedChild<DerivedParent>*`?**

EDIT: I may have found a clue [derivation template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439532/derivation-template-classes).  But it doesn't seem like CRTP will solve this problem.

Comment: why can't ```BaseChild``` just hold a reference/pointer to ```BaseParent``` as a member instead of a type parameter?

Comment: If it did, how would that solve this problem?  (I had tried that initially, but perhaps you have a better approach)

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseParent; // forward declaration

class BaseChild{
public:
  BaseChild(BaseParent* parent_)
    :parent(parent_)
  {}
  BaseParent* parent;
}

class BaseParent {
  virtual BaseChild* createChild() = 0;
}

class DerivedParent;
class DerivedChild: public BaseChild {
public:
  DerivedChild(DerivedParent* parent)
    :BaseChild(parent)
  {}
}

class DerivedParent
  : public BaseParent
{
  BaseChild* createChild() override {
    return new DerivedChild();  
  }
}
```

I don't know the context of the question, so i am not sure whether this is helpful or not.